# Is it better to pass a destructured useContext value to a child component or destructuring it again in the child in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-context

I have searched for an answer but can't find anything relating to this specific query.

I have something resembling the following code:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
   const {facilitiesToDownload} = useEntityContext()

   const isEnabled = facilitiesToDownload?.includes(facility.id)

   return (
      <ChildComponent
         facilitiesToDownload={facilitiesToDownload}
      />
   )
}

const ChildComponent = ({facilitiesToDownload}) => {
   
   const atFacilityLimit = facilitiesToDownload.length >= 3

   return (
      ...blah
   )
}
```

Assuming `ChildComponent` is only ever used inside `ParentComponent`, is it better to destructure `facilitiesToDownload` inside `ChildComponent` or just pass it in as a prop as per the example? Both in terms of best practices and performance.

Comment: Main thing to consider is if your absolute initial context state is `undefined` or not. Destructuring would be a problem then. Otherwise this question will lead to many different opinions. I'd say it mostly depends on your tech stack. There's no performance gain or loss with destructuring --- it's purely for convenience and code reduction.

Comment: Thanks. The initial state will always have a value so it wouldn't be an issue. The tech stack is standard React with AWS as the backend